# Error starting Jetty from mvn jetty:run

Tags: java, maven, jetty

I am using jetty 9.0.6, Java 1.7

I changed the Cassandra driver from Hecto to the DataStax driver version 3.2 and now when I try to run from Maven `mvn jetty:run` I get the following

```
[INFO] web.xml file = file:/Users/scott.gardner/dev/synacor/synacor-service-be-atlas/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
[INFO] Webapp directory = /Users/scott.gardner/dev/synacor/synacor-service-be-atlas/src/main/webapp
[WARNING] Failed startup of context o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@1e1b061{/,file:/Users/scott.gardner/dev/synacor/synacor-service-be-atlas/src/main/webapp/,STARTING}{file:/Users/scott.gardner/dev/synacor/synacor-service-be-atlas/src/main/webapp/}
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 52264
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:1002)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:985)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:944)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:901)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:874)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.parseWebInfLib(AnnotationConfiguration.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1317)
```

This looks similar to the errors that were happening around 2013 from icu4j, bu that does not show up in the dependencies. I am not sure where to look at this point.

Comment: You can look  https://www.mkyong.com/maven/jetty-java-net-bindexception-address-already-in-use/  this link

Answer (score 1):

Its a bad class in a JAR file (or a JAR file that's using a newer bytecode then Jetty 9.0.6 and Java 7 can support).

Jetty 9.0.6 has little debugging for annotation issues, the annotation / bytecode scanning debugging details were added in the Jetty 9.2.x series.

Its about time you upgraded.

Jetty 9.0.x and 9.1.x are EoL (End of Life) now.

Java 7 is also EoPU (End of Public Updates).